# How to access the application deployed in a web server in an amazon ec2 instance from my home machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an amazon ec2 windows instance. And in that instance i have installed WAMP server and deployed a php application.But I can't able to access my application from my home machine. I have enabled all the ports like 8080,443,80 in the instance's security group during creation of my instance. And also I have changed the the instance's firewall settings to allow all networks by entering the port numbers.But still I can't access my web application.So please kindly give me a solution.

Comment: Try it by using a SSH tunnel

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: when I enter the public DNS of my instance in the url of the browser it displays the site is not available.

Comment: How to connect it by ssh tunnel can you please explain sir?

Comment: did u get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Login to the ec2 instance and check if the services are running. Run telnet to see if it can connect. Are you trying to connect via public IP?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to connect via public IP